# Probability density function within [0,1] with specifiable mode

Tags: density-function, continuous-data, univariate

I needed a probability density function which worked on the interval $[0,1]$, had kind of a bell shape, and had an adjustable mode / peak $p$.

I thought of a pdf $f(x|p)$, given by
\begin{equation}
f(x|p) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l l l }
 \frac{ (x^{- \ln 2/\ln p})^2 \cdot (1-x^{- \ln 2/\ln p})^2 }{ \log(p) 
 \left( 
\frac{x^{1-\frac{4 \log 2}{\log p}}}{\log(p) - 4\log(2)} 
-\frac{2 x^{1-\frac{3 \log 2}{\log p}}}{\log(p) - 3\log(2)} 
+\frac{x^{1-\frac{2 \log 2}{\log p}}}{\log(p) - 2\log(2)} 
  \right) } &\quad \text{ for } 0<x<1 \\
0  &\quad \text{ otherwise}  
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
which

- has a peak at $x=p$ for $0<p<1$.
- $P(X\le 0) = P(X\ge 1) = 0$
- has a shape similar to the bell shape
- looks skewed to the left for $p>1$ and to the right for $0<p<1$

Or equivalently:
\begin{equation}
f(x|p) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l l l }
 \frac{ (x^a)^2 \cdot (1-x^a)^2 } { (4a+1)^{-1} - 2(3a+1)^{-1} + (2a+1)^{-1} } &\quad \text{ for } 0<x<1 \\
0  &\quad \text{ otherwise}  
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
which

which has its peak at $p=-\frac{\log 2}{\log x}$

Is there a similar pdf (or exactly this one) used in literature?
What is it called?

**PS**: note that the given pdf is not symmetric: $f(x|1-p) \neq f(1-x |p) $

Comment: Are you familiar with the beta distribution? It's only defined on the [0,1] interval and its mode can be shifted with alternative parameter specifications.

Comment: Yes, but it is not bell shaped. My function has $f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$...

Comment: Do you have a particular definition of "bell shaped" in mind?

Comment: All beta distributions with both parameters exceeding $2$ have $f'(0)=f'(1)=1$, are unimodal, and can be adjusted to place that mode anywhere within $(0,1)$.

Comment: Well, it is bell shaped in the sense that its derivatives are zero at $0$ and $1$ and it has one mode. It is in that respect that my distribution is significantly different from the beta distribution, since a beta distribution has $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(1)<0$.

Comment: Ummm... how can you assert that both $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(0)\gt 0$?  Indeed, for $a=1$ your distribution *is* a Beta distribution (with parameters $(3,3)$).

Comment: Angelorf - Given @whuber had already clearly stated the conditions under which your claim about the beta distribution was false, your last comment needed to address those facts. You don't simply reiterate a contradiction. Explain why you think he's wrong (hint: he isn't, but attempting to explain it will help reveal what seems may be an important gap in your understanding - one that will be worth your time to explore and set right).

Comment: The mistake I made was that for the beta distribution $f'(0;\alpha, \beta)>0 $ and $ f'(1;\alpha, \beta)<0$ only hold for $1<\alpha,\beta<2$. The mistake that @whuber made is that for $\alpha,\beta>2$ we actually have $f'(0;\alpha, \beta) = f'(1;\alpha, \beta)=0$ instead of $1$. With such parameters the beta-distribution _does_ have a bell shape.

Comment: @Glen_b : what seemed to you to be a reiteration of a contradiction was actually the result of a misunderstanding caused by mistakes we both made. I was trying to explain the necessary conditions for the function to have a bell shape and these conditions were not met by what whuber (falsely) said about the beta distribution.

Comment: I was referring to his second comment (which unless I missed something, correctly fixes the typo in his first comment) and your reply to that comment.

Comment: I am seriously doubting whether you can see a comment that I for some reason can't. For me his second comment is the one starting with "Ummm..." and I hadn't replied to that before your first post.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing out the typo: I had re-read that first comment several times and *still* saw the "$f'(0)=f'(1)=0$" that I had intended (echoing the preceding comment by Angelorf).  Angelorf, I apologize for possibly causing confusion with that.

Comment: All is clear in the end, so no problem!

Comment: Angelorf - my apologies; I appear to have misread the order of messages.

Comment: @whuber I initially read your first comment as you did.

Comment: All has been forgiven. :) Thanks for commenting. Thanks to your remarks I found out that using the normal Beta distribution already suffices for what I was trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pdf is similar to the [generalized Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Beta_distribution) of the first kind, which is obtained by raising a Beta variable to a power.

Comment: My distribution seems to be a special case of the generalized Beta distribution. With parameters $p=2+1/a$ , $q=3$ and $b=1$, the remaining part should be equal, since both distributions have a volume of 1. So $|a| \cdot(b^{ap} B(p,q))^{-1} = ((4a+1)^{-1} - 2(3a+1)^{-1} + (2a+1)^{-1})^{-1}$